# Cannot open/run TERMINAL and software-center after PARTIAL UPGRADE prompted by Ubuntu

Tags: software-center, gnome-terminal, locale, partial-upgrade

I cannot open terminal or software-center after installing the partial-upgrade prompted by Ubuntu.

In UXTERM, when I type gnome-terminal, I get the output as:

```
(process:10308): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.Terminal exited with status 8
```

In UXTERM, when I type software-center, I get the output as:

```
(process:23592): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
ERROR:root:DebFileApplication import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from debfile import DebFileApplication, DebFileOpenError
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/debfile.py", line 25, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.db.application import Application, AppDetails
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/application.py", line 28, in <module>
    import softwarecenter.distro
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 199, in <module>
    distro_instance = _get_distro()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 174, in _get_distro
    module = __import__(distro_module_name, globals(), locals(), [], -1)
ImportError: No module named kali
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 128, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app import SoftwareCenterAppGtk3
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 54, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.db.application import Application
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/application.py", line 28, in <module>
    import softwarecenter.distro
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 199, in <module>
    distro_instance = _get_distro()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 174, in _get_distro
    module = __import__(distro_module_name, globals(), locals(), [], -1)
```

After searching, I found out it maybe due to locale issues.
In UXTERM, when I typed `locale`, I get the output as:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_IN
LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
LC_CTYPE="en_IN"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IN"
LC_TIME="en_IN"
LC_COLLATE="en_IN"
LC_MONETARY="en_IN"
LC_MESSAGES="en_IN"
LC_PAPER="en_IN"
LC_NAME="en_IN"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IN"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IN"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IN"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IN"
LC_ALL=
```

And now when I try to fix it, now `uxterm` won't open. When I try to open it, it says:

```
uxterm tried unsuccessfully to use locale en_IN.UTF-8 by setting $LANG to "en_IN.UTF-8".
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your locale seems to have been corrupted somehow, and needs to be regenerated. I suggest that you open a console window (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and log in. Then try to regenerate all the locales by running

```
sudo locale-gen --purge
```